# (Java) How do I make a database delete a stored value until the value has been stored more than 5 times?

Tags: java, database, memory, time, repeat

I'm kinda trying to make a VERY basic replication of memory in a way.
Basically, I want my program to take in user input and forget it (delete it from database)after about 18 seconds, but remember it (permanently store it in database) if input is repeated 5 times or more.

Here's the code I have so far (It's a JavaFX program by the way):

```
    TextField userText = new TextField();
    Timeline time;
    String message;
    message = userText.getText();
    ArrayList<String> memory = new ArrayList<>();


    if(message.contains(message) && message.contains(" ") && !memory.contains(message)){
            String[] splitMessage = message.split(" ");/*To split the sentence*/

            for(int i = 0; i<splitMessage.length; i++)
            memory.add(splitMessage[i]); /*To add the individual words of a sentence*/
            memory.add(message); /*To add the sentence itself*/
            time = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(18000),
                    ae -> memory.remove(message)));
            time.play();
        }
```

So I have this so far and it works at storing data for 18 seconds. But I want it  so the data is permanently stored into "memory" after the program has attempted to store the same message more than 5 times, whether consecutively or in random order.
Is there a way to do this?

Hope this made sense. I'm known for not wording questions properly haha.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Does the 5 times or more criteria need to be met before the 18 seconds are up to force permanent storage?

Comment: Does the 5 times need to apply to separate sessions?

Comment: What happens if input happens during the 18 seconds? Does it count as one of the five retries or not?

Comment: @Brett Walker - Both during the 18 seconds and after. So basically, how many seconds it takes for the user to input the string 5 times doesn't matter.

Comment: The 18 seconds is just for the data removal. Permanently storing the data is separate from the 18 seconds and will be stored after 5 repetitions regardless of time. Thanks for looking through it guys :).

Comment: If I add it 4 times and close the program, should that reset the counter or does it need to persist?

Comment: Your data structures are going have an additional layer complexity here because you program doesn't want to forget at all any message. It needs to flag a message as effectively forgotten if it is young (< 18 seconds since it has last been seen) AND not permanently remembered. You have to store along side the message the last seen time stamp and the seen count.

Comment: @BoDidely - If you know how to make the counter not reset itself that would be awesome as I don't know how to do that :D.

Comment: @BrettWalker - Can you please explain. Sorry, I'm not the brightest bulb haha.

Comment: With you limited code above and the unusual requirements I am reluctant to elaborate further with a coded example. Could provide the back story for these requirements? Why do you have these requirements?

Comment: @MaxEchendu yes I'm curious why the items need to be added to the database for 18 second instead of once permanently after 5 attempted adds

Comment: @BrettWalker - Alright :) ...basically, I'm trying to replicate memory (BASIC REPLICATION)...I'm trying to tell the program "Hey, if the User Input is not in the memory, store it temporarily for 18 seconds. But if something has been repeated more than 5 times, store it permanently". Kind of like making the program remember something and memorise it.

Comment: @BoDidely - I wanted to add the items in the database for 18 seconds because I want the program to remember what the user has typed in the user input...but see it as too unimportant to bother remembering it. However, if the user repeats it more than 5 times, the program then thinks (hypothetically) "Well this seems important, so I'll store it in my long-term memory to retrieve it when needed". Kinda like humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt at providing an additional layer of complexity to suffice your needs (if I understand them correctly).

I would replace:

```
ArrayList<String> memory = new ArrayList<>();
```

with

```
MemorySpace memorySpace = new MemorySpace();
```

The only problem that I see is the proper interpretation of:

```
!memory.contains(message);
```

It could be

```
memorySpace.isMemoryPermanent(message);
```

or

```
memorySpace.isMemoryActive(message);
```

Hopefully the API is clear enough for you to understand my intentions and how it could help in your situation. As I understand it a word is remembered permanently the first time but a sentence needs five time to become permanent.

```
public class MemorySpace {
  private final Map<String, Memory> memorySpace;

  public MemorySpace() {
    this.memorySpace = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void addWord(String word) {
     Memory m = this.memorySpace.get(word);

     if (m == null) {
        this.memorySpace.put(word, new Memory(true, word))
     }
  }

  public void addSentence(String sentence) {
     Memory m = this.memorySpace.get(sentence);

     if (m == null) {
        this.memorySpace.put(sentence, new Memory(false, sentence))
     }
     else {
        m.increaseSeenCount();
     }
  }

  public boolean isMemoryPermanent(String workOrSentence) {
    Memory m = this.memorySpace.get(wordOrSentence)

    if (m != null) {
      return m.isMemoryPermanent();
    }

    return false;
  }

  public boolean isMemoryActive(String workOrSentence) {
    Memory m = this.memorySpace.get(wordOrSentence)

    if (m != null) {
      return m.isMemoryActive();
    }

    return false;
  }

  private class Memory {
    private final boolean isWordMemory;
    private final String wordOrSentence;

    private       int seenCount;
    private       long lastSeenAtMilliseconds;

    Memory(boolean isWordMemory, String newWordOrSentence) {
      this.isWordMemory = isWordMemory;
      this.wordOrSentence = newWordOrSentence;
      this.seenCount = 1;
      this.lastSeenAtMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    boolean isWordMemory() {
      return this.isWordMemory;
    }

    void increaseSeenCount() {
      if (!this.isWordMemory) {
        if (this.seenCount < 5) {  // Stop overflow
          this.seenCount++;
        }

        this.lastSeenAtMilliseconds = System.milliseconds();
      }
    }

    void isMemoryPermanent() {
      return this.isWordMemory || this.seenCount >= 5;
    }

    void isMemoryActive() {
      return this.isWordMemory || this.isMemoryPermanent() || (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.lastSeenAtMilliseconds) < (18 * 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU 200000000000000000000 TIMES...you have no idea how much this has helped me :D.